# Is it safe to abort the Debian installer while it's downloading the nonessential packages?

Tags: debian, debian-installer

I decided after a while of using Ubuntu that it wasn't right for me, so I decided to install Debian 11 instead. (I had nothing important on the computer.)

I got it all working at the beginning, but stupidly decided to use my phone's hotspot (don't ask, please) since I couldn't get my WiFi to work with it. I realise in retrospect that I shouldn't have done that.

It installed the essential system stuff, but it's stuck at the 126th non-essential file. I suspect it's because of my choice in installation network. Can I shut down the computer and try again using Ethernet instead? Will it cause any unrecoverable issues? Thanks :)

Comment: With some fiddling, you should be able to get it to continue: Files are down-loaded over TCP. TCP is all about working over unreliable networks. Unfortunately, I could not tell you what fiddling to do. Just try stuff. If all else fails, try again. Next time, you can do a more minimal install, and install the extra stuff, when it is up and running.

Answer (score 0):

You can shut the computer down and try again; the installer won’t pick up where it left off, but you will be able to install again.

Comment: Thanks! You just saved me :D I was only worried about whether it would work at all, not whether it would start from the same place.